# no access to proxy resurces(DB, LDAP)

Tags: wildfly

I'm working on jee app. At home I'm using proxy to access company DB and LDAP servers. At work my config works fine but when i want to develop at home wildfly don't have access to proxied resources.

I can connect to DB using pgAdmin at home(the same situation is with LDAP), so i this is clearly widfly limitation.

Do you know what could be a problem? I have no idea why using DB client i have access but widfly got exception(i'm using the same url).

> Unexpected HTTP response: 500
>
> Request {
>       "address" => [
>           ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
>           ("data-source" => "mmDS")
>       ],
>       "operation" => "test-connection-in-pool" }
>
> Response
>
> Internal Server Error {
>       "outcome" => "failed",
>       "failure-description" => "JBAS010440: failed to invoke operation: JBAS010447: Connection is not valid",
>       "rolled-back" => true }

Comment: What do your connection strings look like?

Comment: I cannot put url but i made screens. Urls are the same in both configurations http://i58.tinypic.com/202zc7.png  http://i61.tinypic.com/2irkqh3.png